# Unity2D: How to get object to move forward

Tags: c#, scripting, unity-game-engine

I am trying to run a simple script to get an object to move forward within unity.

My code is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveToHold : MonoBehaviour {

    private float traveledDistance;
    public int moveSpeed = 10;
    private bool isMoving;
    public GameObject Aircraft;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (isMoving == true)
        {
            //Aircraft.transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
            Aircraft.transform.position += transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime; 
        }

    }

    public void move ()
    {
        isMoving = true;
        Debug.Log(isMoving);
    }
}
```

As far as I can see, the transform.position should work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What behavior are you currently seeing? Does the aircraft move at all? Are you getting any errors? Have you assigned a GameObject to the `Aircraft` variable? Is the `move()` function being called and do you see the expected log entry?

Comment: Do you have a Rigidbody2D on the gameobject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing :

```
Aircraft.transform.position += transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
```

to :

```
Aircraft.transform.position += transform.right * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
```

Sometimes with unity2D the forward axis is the Z so you're pushing it inside the Z axis which you won't see. Right will move it on the x axis.

Comment: Ahh..that's got it! Thank you :)

Comment: How would I get the script to slow down?..When I run it at the moment, it just pings off into infinity.

Comment: You want it to stay the same speed?

Comment: Preferably, although I just need it to move much slower.

Comment: You can lower your moveSpeed variable if you just need it to go slower.

Comment: Ah yer. For some reason, I changed it in the script, but it was still set to 10 within the inspector, so it still pinged off. Thank's once again.

Comment: @DanielColthart: That's expected behavior. Inspector values can be different from - and will always override - public instance variable values in the script.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to apply your position to the RigidBody object rather than the aircraft. If I'm guessing right, that should be your aircraft's parent.  Try:

```
Aircraft.parent.transform.position += transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
```